# Java - Loop performance drop

Tags: java, performance, loops

The scenario goes as such...

I have two functions Function A() and Function B(). The Function A() has a for-loop which calls Function B() in every iteration. Function B() has a for-loop which iterates around 10 million times.

```
Function A()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Function B();
}

Function B()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        certain_operations()
}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that, A()'s for-loop's first iteration takes 1 minute to execute, second iteration takes 2 mins, third iteration takes 4 mins and so on... Even though the number of iterations is the same, the subsequent loop execution in A() increases. I have generated the following logs.

```
Cluster :  1
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:36:20,496 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:37:11,762 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:37:11,762 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 1 - Critical Operations : 160000

Cluster :  2
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:37:11,767 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:38:02,365 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:38:02,365 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 2 - Critical Operations : 40000

Cluster :  3
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:38:02,366 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:41:35,675 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:41:35,675 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 3 - Critical Operations : 80000

Cluster :  4
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:41:35,676 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:50:17,875 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:50:17,875 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 4 - Critical Operations : 120000

Cluster :  5
 INFO 2014-09-17 16:50:17,886 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:02:42,819 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:02:42,819 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 5 - Critical Operations : 160000

Cluster :  6
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:02:42,820 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:07:01,916 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:07:01,916 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 6 - Critical Operations : 40000

Cluster :  7
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:07:01,917 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:16:21,122 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:16:21,122 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 7 - Critical Operations : 100000

Cluster :  8
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:16:21,123 [pool-8-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:22:40,371 [pool-8-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-17 17:22:40,371 [pool-8-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 8 - Critical Operations : 60000
```

**HERE, THE TIME BETWEEN Print 1 AND Print 2 IS THE EXECUTION TIME OF Function A()'s ONE ITERATION.**

Any idea why this problem is occurring ? Suggestions regarding how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

This is my code in case there are anomalies you can get...

```
Function A()
{
    for(Data d : packList)              
            List<Data> region  = getRegionData(d, dataList, axisEN, eN, cluster++);         

            //dataList -> 10 million records
            //d -> single instance of dataList
}

public List<Data> getRegionData(Data data, List<Data> listData, int axisEN, int eN, int cluster)    //Function B()
    {   
        List<Data> region = new ArrayList<Data>();
        Data temp = new Data();
        int distance;

        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(), "Print 1");
        for(Data d : listData)
        {
            temp.setOffnet(java.lang.Math.abs(data.getOffnet() - d.getOffnet()));
            temp.setOnnet(java.lang.Math.abs(data.getOnnet() - d.getOnnet()));
            temp.setInet(java.lang.Math.abs(data.getInet() - d.getInet()));

            distance = temp.getOffnet() + temp.getOnnet() + temp.getInet();

            if(distance <= eN)
                if(temp.getOffnet() <= axisEN && temp.getOnnet() <= axisEN && temp.getInet() <= axisEN)
                {                   
                    d.setId(listData.indexOf(d));
                    d.setCluster(cluster);
                    d.setDistance(distance);
                    d.setCount(d.getCount() + 1);
                    region.add(d);  
                }
        }



        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(), "Print 2");
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.info, this.getClass().getName(), "Cluster " + cluster + " : " + region.size());
        return region;
    }
}
```

.
.

---

EDIT 1 : Removing the listData.indexOf(d)

---

```
 Cluster :  1
 INFO 2014-09-18 14:58:28,306 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 14:59:04,233 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 14:59:04,233 [pool-1-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 1  - Critical Operations : 120000
 Cluster :  2
 INFO 2014-09-18 14:59:04,236 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:01:32,566 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:01:32,566 [pool-2-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 2  - Critical Operations : 120000
 Cluster :  3
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:01:32,567 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:09:15,873 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:09:15,873 [pool-3-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 3  - Critical Operations : 200000
 Cluster :  4
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:09:15,874 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:13:30,019 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:13:30,019 [pool-4-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 4  - Critical Operations : 80000
 Cluster :  5
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:13:30,019 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:24:10,602 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:24:10,602 [pool-5-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 5  - Critical Operations : 160000
 Cluster :  6
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:24:10,603 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:29:47,132 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:29:47,132 [pool-6-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 6  - Critical Operations : 60000
 Cluster :  7
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:29:47,133 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 1
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:38:49,182 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Print 2
 INFO 2014-09-18 15:38:49,182 [pool-7-thread-1][] com.bng.dbscan.util.GenerateCluster - Cluster 6  - Critical Operations : 60000
```

PrintGCDetails for three iterations

```
After Iter1
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 952K [0x9ee80000, 0xa0300000, 0xb3540000)
  eden space 15872K, 6% used [0x9ee80000,0x9ef6e248,0x9fe00000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0xa0080000,0xa0080000,0xa0300000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x9fe00000,0x9fe00000,0xa0080000)
 ParOldGen       total 41728K, used 0K [0x76140000, 0x78a00000, 0x9ee80000)
  object space 41728K, 0% used [0x76140000,0x76140000,0x78a00000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 1771K [0x72140000, 0x73140000, 0x76140000)
  object space 16384K, 10% used [0x72140000,0x722faf00,0x73140000)


After Iter2
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 952K [0x9ef00000, 0xa0380000, 0xb35c0000)
  eden space 15872K, 6% used [0x9ef00000,0x9efee260,0x9fe80000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0xa0100000,0xa0100000,0xa0380000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x9fe80000,0x9fe80000,0xa0100000)
 ParOldGen       total 41728K, used 0K [0x761c0000, 0x78a80000, 0x9ef00000)
  object space 41728K, 0% used [0x761c0000,0x761c0000,0x78a80000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 1771K [0x721c0000, 0x731c0000, 0x761c0000)
  object space 16384K, 10% used [0x721c0000,0x7237af00,0x731c0000)


After Iter3
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 952K [0x9ee80000, 0xa0300000, 0xb3540000)
  eden space 15872K, 6% used [0x9ee80000,0x9ef6e248,0x9fe00000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0xa0080000,0xa0080000,0xa0300000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x9fe00000,0x9fe00000,0xa0080000)
 ParOldGen       total 41728K, used 0K [0x76140000, 0x78a00000, 0x9ee80000)
  object space 41728K, 0% used [0x76140000,0x76140000,0x78a00000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 1771K [0x72140000, 0x73140000, 0x76140000)
  object space 16384K, 10% used [0x72140000,0x722faf00,0x73140000)
```

Comment: Make sure to post valid code; everywhere.

Comment: I have done that... Please look down.. :)

Comment: May be due to garbage collection? Or the data size varies. Please check size of listData and packList at every iteration.

Comment: listData is 10 million in every iteration. The critical operations (within the if clause in Function B()) has been mentioned in the logs.

Comment: Random change, try adding final identifier to functions and Data class declaration. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: What JVM version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

The clue is `listData.indexOf(d)` that makes the algorithm complexity quadratic.
Replace `indexOf` with a simple loop counter and enjoy the performance difference.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I commented the indexOf() statement and tried running. Its still having the issue... Have shared the logs in EDIT 1 ...

Comment: @StackAddict Try adding `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` JVM option to see what's happening in the heap.

Comment: I performed PrintGCDetails while the code was running at three different times. Have included the results under EDIT 1

Comment: @StackAddict I meant adding JVM option to the actual application run. Looks like you've run a separate JVM 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

just my 2 cents:

These operations could cause the performance issue...

```
    List<Data> region = new ArrayList<Data>();
    Data temp = new Data();
    ...
    region.add(..);
```

I would try these steps:

- if possible (!), try to alloc region list one time
- try to alloc region list like this: `new ArrayList<Data>(initSize)`
- `Data temp` is not realy necessary, avoid `new` try to use primitivs like float, int etc..
- try to mess execution time without `Logger`

Comment: Thanks for your comments... Actually, I have written a log for critical operations, which is the region size. That is, the number of times the control has entered the inner if() clause. If its zero then, the execution time for the iteration is less than a second. So, the statements in if() clause are affecting the performance. Moreover, I need the region data for processing. Hence, I cannot compromise with region.add() unless there is an alternative